# Hosting Mercurial HG via VisualSVN Server

Tags: mercurial, hosting, cgi, visualsvn

I have tried to host a Mercurial HG repository using a Scriptalias.

ScriptAlias /hg/ "htdocs/hgwebdir.cgi"

If I go to Chrome it display the contents of the cgi file. In IE it does render however images and links are not displayed. In either case the repository I want to display is not shown.

Has anyone managed to get this working with VisualSVN? Also will this work if I have windows authentication and https?

Comment: I have trying to figure this out for two days now!! Wish I had an answer.

Comment: You must use an absolute path for the last argument of ScriptAlias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a alternative setup using mod_wsgi (fast!), combined repository directory, and you can manage Mercurial repository level access from the VisualSVN Server GUI.

Download [mod_wsgi.so for Apache 2.2 Win32](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py26-3.0.so) and place in "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin".

Copy hgwebdir.wsgi from your Mercurial installation (contrib directory) to "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\".   It should look something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:\Program Files\Mercurial\library")
from mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod import hgwebdir
application = hgwebdir('hgweb.config')
```

Create the config file "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\hgweb.config".

```
[paths]
/ = c:/Repositories/*
```

Paste the following in "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\conf\httpd-custom.conf".  You should adjust the Auth* values based on the  section of httpd.conf.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module bin/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias /hg "hgwebdir.wsgi"

<Location /hg/>
    AuthName "Mercurial Repositories"
    AuthType VisualSVN
    AuthzVisualSVNAccessFile "C:/Repositories/authz-windows"
    AuthnVisualSVNBasic on
    AuthnVisualSVNIntegrated off
    AuthnVisualSVNUPN Off

    SVNParentPath "C:/Repositories/"

    require valid-user
</Location>
```

Create a Mercurial repository:

```
hg init C:\Repositories\hgtest
```

You should now be able to access /hg through your browser, and manage repository level authorization through the VisualSVN Server tool.

Comment: I think I am very close to getting this working, however I am getting an error 'Exception occurred processing WSGI script mercurial' &   "File "mercurial\\hgweb\\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 103, in __call__'. Is the latest Mecurial 1.5.1 compiled against Python 2.6?

Comment: 5 seconds after posting my last comment I finally got this to work! Copied Templates folder to the library folder as per previous answer.

Extra Steps to follow:
1. Extract libraries.zip in Mercurial install to a folder called libraries.
2. Copy Templates folder to the libraries folder.
3. Make sure you install Python 2.6.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: mod_wsgi module included in VisualSVN Server distribution since version 3.3.0: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v3.3.0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Python 2.6 installed and working, here are the steps that I took.

Obtain "mod_cgi.so" built for [Apache 2.2 Win32](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/httpd/binaries/win32/) and place it in "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin".

Paste the following in "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\conf\httpd-custom.conf"

```
LoadModule cgi_module bin/mod_cgi.so
ScriptAliasMatch ^/hg(.*) "cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi$1"
```

Create the cgi-bin directory, "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\cgi-bin".  And place [hgweb.cgi](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-stable/file/tip/hgweb.cgi) in it.  Make sure it looks similar to the following:

```
#!c:/Python26/python.exe -u

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:\Program Files\Mercurial\library")

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

from mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod import hgwebdir
import mercurial.hgweb.wsgicgi as wsgicgi

application = hgwebdir('hgweb.config')
wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

Create a file called hgweb.config in the cgi-bin directory.

```
[paths]
/ = c:/HgRepositories/*
```

Copied "C:\Program Files\Mercurial\templates" to "C:\Program Files\Mercurial\library\templates".

Create "C:\HgRepositories" folder and "hg init c:\HgRepositories\test".

Restart VisualSVN Server, open browser, enjoy your Mercurial repository.

Answer (score 0):

> Starting with version 1.6 of Mercurial, the hgwebdir.wsgi script has
>   been unified with the hgweb.wsgi script. Wherever hgwebdir.wsgi is
>   referred to in these directions, you can substitute the hgweb.wsgi
>   script instead.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/modwsgi

Answer (score -1):

You can run hgwebdir behind different authentication and https modules just fine, provided your webserver handles them before the REMOTE_USER variable is handed off to the CGI.

I don't know visualsvn, but your ScriptAlias looks a lot like Apache.  Do you need an [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) line for .cgi?

Comment: Is that AddHandler line supposed to be all that is needed to execute CGI on a regular apache server?

Comment: In Apache you can authorize the execution of files using "ExecCGI", "AddHandler cgi-script .cgi", and "ScriptAlias".  I use the later two.