# mercurial equivalent of visual svn server

Tags: svn, mercurial, visualsvn-server

*I know this has been asked in the past, but those questions are a few years old so I figured there might be some new information.*

I'm working at a company that's not a software company but we also have a few programmers. Today we are using a visual svn server to host our repositories and tortoiseSVN to interact with the repositories. I'm not a big fan of subversion since I want to be able to commit without updating/merging, so I've proposed a change to mercurial instead.

We still want to run a server with all the repositories on our own network so we want something that looks like this.

[image]

It would also be nice if there was a way to browse the repositories through a web browser so that our non programmers can also access the repositories. I've searched for quite a bit to see if I can find a mercural version of visual svn server but I haven't had much luck. I found this thing called HgLab which looks nice, but might be a bit overkill for our needs.

So to my question. Does anyone know a mercurial equivalent of visual svn server that's pretty straightforward to setup on a windows server?

Comment: err mercurial itself , you can either host it on your own web server via hgweb or it comes with its own bundled web server (hg serve)

Comment: @jk. We actually tried doing it through hg serve first, but we only managed to host one repository at a time. Didn't dig too much in to it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my office, we use Kallithea (https://kallithea-scm.org/) , on Windows Server 2008 R2.

The only issue we had on setup was due to our corporate firewall - we had to manually install some dependencies.

Some further references:

- http://docs.kallithea-scm.org/en/latest/setup.html#setting-up-kallithea
- http://docs.kallithea-scm.org/en/latest/installation_iis.html

There's also RhodeCode (https://rhodecode.com/), from which Kallithea was forked due to a licencing dispute. I don't have any experience with installing RhodeCode, but I believe it will also be an alternative for you.

Don't be worried about overkill if it does what you need in a simple way (without the "overkill" bits getting in the way).

We started our Mercurial journey by hosting hgweb on IIS, and adding a repository meant opening an RDP session to the server, running hg init, manually editing hgrc to add relevant information, remembering to check that the correct users have access to the folders and so on.

In Kallithea? Simply click the "add repository" button on its landing page, and fill in the form it opens. It has other features, like changeset reviews/comments, which we haven't used much (just testing how it works, really). But as the features we don't use aren't in the way, we don't mind.

Comment: RhodeCode also now since 3.X supports SVN, and  has windows installer. So it's a nice way to still migrate to Mercurial and keep your legacy SVN repos in one place

Answer (score 2):

> mercural version of visual svn server

[Hosting Mercurial HG via VisualSVN Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428870/hosting-mercurial-hg-via-visualsvn-server) accepted answer may help

In common, you can|have to read [Publishing Repositories](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories) Wiki-page, on which most (all?) up-to-date solutions noted and shortly compared.

Short-list in order "From simple to complex"

- [SCM Manager](https://www.scm-manager.org/) (pure Java)
- [RhodeCode](https://rhodecode.com/) (Python)
- [Apache Allura](http://allura.apache.org/) (a lot of dependencies and it's more *Forge, than enterprise-tool)
- [Assembla Private Install](https://www.assembla.com/portfolio/portfolio-private-install) (may be own install or hosted solution, support for Mercurial was dropped some time ago in mainline's [Assembla Portfolio](https://www.assembla.com/portfolio) /but it's question of money, I think/)

**Note:** From my POV, SCM Manager (with set of must-have plugins) can be good starting position to assess the needs and opportunities of idea